# How to show source revision details when GitLab is the actual source of AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: aws-lambda, gitlab, aws-codepipeline

By following the ["git to s3 using webhooks" guide](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/git-to-s3-using-webhooks/), I have connected GitLab with CodePipeline.

I want to display the GitLab commit id (or revision details) in CodePipeline, similar to what happens when GitHub is connected to CodePipeline.

However, currently the CodePipeline source stage only shows the S3 version id, which is not representative of the GitLab commit id.

From the above guide, GitLab is already passing `commit_id` and `commit_url` to the lambda function `ZipDlLambda`. I am thinking maybe I can let lambda pass `commit_id` and `commit_url` to CodePipeline.
Hopefully this'd allow me to show the commit id somewhere on the CodePipeline page, and the commit url somewhere in a manual approval page (so that that an approver may review the commit).

Does anyone know if this is possible? (and if so, how?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The S3 source action doesn't support "tunneling" commit information from an external source to CodePipeline.

You can, however, use a [custom action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-custom-action.html) to pull source from GitLab and provide commit information to CodePipeline. This would mean creating a worker for the custom action that polls for work, so you'd have to decide if having the commit information is worth it to you.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, looks like a new knowledge to me. I am glad to learn. Looks like it is not a easy job? because you said I have to decide whether it is worthwhile?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a link to CodePipeline's documentation about custom actions. One addendum to the documentation: it describes using an EC2 instance for the worker, but it's also possible to use a Lambda function with CloudWatch to periodically trigger the Lambda function and poll for work.